# Java Spark3 avoid lambda casting: reference is ambigous

Tags: java, apache-spark

I've been developing a lot on Spark2 and I'm trying to move my codebase in Spark3.

The problem is that all my lambda code with the Datasets is no longer working, the reference to map is ambigous :

```
java: reference to map is ambiguous
  both method <U>map(scala.Function1<T,U>,org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder<U>) in org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset and method <U>map(org.apache.spark.api.java.function.MapFunction<T,U>,org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder<U>) in org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset match
```

Here is a quick code to replicate it on Spark3 :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkSession
                .builder()
                .master("local[1]")
                .getOrCreate()
                .createDataset(Arrays.asList("A", "b", "C"), Encoders.STRING())
                // error is here
                .map(v -> v.toLowerCase(), Encoders.STRING())
                .show();
    }
```

This error aslo applies to every other Dataset transformations like filter, flatMap, ...

I tried different version of Java (8, 11 and 17), but the error is always the same.

In the past, I used to have a similar issue with the Scala plugin with Intellij, but now, even Java cannot compile this code with Spark3.

It doesn't even work with method reference. The only fix is eiter a cast :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkSession
                .builder()
                .master("local[1]")
                .getOrCreate()
                .createDataset(Arrays.asList("A", "b", "C"), Encoders.STRING())
                // A cast fixes the issue
                .map((MapFunction<String, String>) v -> v.toLowerCase(), Encoders.STRING())
                .show();
    }
```

Or by creating a class that implements the wanted function

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkSession
                .builder()
                .master("local[1]")
                .getOrCreate()
                .createDataset(Arrays.asList("A", "b", "C"), Encoders.STRING())
                .map(new LowerCaseSparkFunction(), Encoders.STRING())
                .show();
    }

}

class LowerCaseSparkFunction implements MapFunction<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String call(String s) throws Exception {
        return s.toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

I find the casting solution to be too verbose and I need to update a lot of code for it to work. Is there any other solution ?

Answer (score 0):

A small family of helper functions (or use Scala) e.g.:

```java
public static <T, R> MapFunction<T, R> mapF(MapFunction<T,R> function)
{
    return function;
}

.map(mapF(v -> v.toLowerCase()), Encoders.STRING())
```

is a third option, type inference will improve and your most difficult task is to remember the function name and imports.

Add a static function to the util class for each ambiguity you have in your source code.